# How to add value from one column to another column and row?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a table:

```
+----+--------+---------+--------+-------+
| Id | MainId | MainUrl |  Url   | Name  |
+----+--------+---------+--------+-------+
|  1 |        |         | /item1 | Item1 |
|  2 |        | /item1  | /item2 | Item2 |
|  3 |        | /item1  | /item3 | Item3 |
|  4 |        | /item1  | /item4 | Item4 |
|  5 |        | /item2  | /item5 | Item5 |
+----+--------+---------+--------+-------+
```

How can I add Id of the row, which is linked from MainUrl to Url, into MainId column? So in the end I have:

```
+----+--------+---------+--------+-------+
| Id | MainId | MainUrl |  Url   | Name  |
+----+--------+---------+--------+-------+
|  1 |        |         | /item1 | Item1 |
|  2 |    1   | /item1  | /item2 | Item2 |
|  3 |    1   | /item1  | /item3 | Item3 |
|  4 |    1   | /item1  | /item4 | Item4 |
|  5 |        | /item2  | /item5 | Item5 |
+----+--------+---------+--------+-------+
```

I know that it is not very efficient and common way to link corresponding rows but I need it for my own purposes. Please avoid using double links (!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `join` in the update:

```
update t join
       t tt
       on t.mainurl = tt.url and t.mainurl <> ''
    set t.mainid = tt.id;
```

Comment: This request updated all my rows, added `t.MainUrl != ''` after `on t.mainurl = tt.url`